# Dynamically change name of ng-model in html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

I want to change my ng-model name (in the html input tag) for each input tag dynamically. For example if my json file looks like:

```
[{cows: 0, pigs: 14, roosters: 2, horses: 23, goats: 21}]
```

and I am iterating through the properties of the json object ("items") using ng-repeat, what should I put in for ng-model="????" to bind that specific input with the specific object property (animal)?

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form class="idea item">
        <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in items[0]">
            <label>{{key}}</label>
            <input type="range" value="{{value}}" min="0" max="4" ng-model="????" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" ng-click="save()" />
    </form>
</div>
```

If I wrote it out statically without using ng-repeat, the inputs would look like:

```
<input type="range" value="{{value}}" min="0" max="4" ng-model="items[0].cows" />
<input type="range" value="{{value}}" min="0" max="4" ng-model="items[0].pigs" />
<input type="range" value="{{value}}" min="0" max="4" ng-model="items[0].roosters" />
<input type="range" value="{{value}}" min="0" max="4" ng-model="items[0].horses" />
<input type="range" value="{{value}}" min="0" max="4" ng-model="items[0].goats" />
```

However, I want this to be dynamic as I don't know what property names to expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the associative indexing:

```
<input type="range" value="{{value}}" min="0" max="4" ng-model="items[0][key]" />
```

In other words, you can always access variables via the associative array.  The following are equivalent:

```
item[0].pigs
item[0]['pigs']
```

You can use that to your advantage, since you know the `key` in your repeater.